How to ajaxify all pages of my Wp Site
I want to ajaxify all my wordpress site pages, how to do that. Is there a plugin for that? Please guide. thank you

I would not recommend this at all. A lot of WordPress caching solutions don't support AJAX so it will greatly slow down your site. It's also terrible for SEO. But if you must, it's going to depend entirely on your theme. The javascript needed for this will have to be coded to know where to pull the main content from and what part of your site is being replaced. Sure, you could load the full page - but that would defeat the whole "point" of ajaxifying your site, which I assume is that when someone clicks a link it only replaces the main content and the header/footer remain static.

I fully agree with you that caching plugins might not support this and this can slow down the things. The the thing is do you know there is a feature called asynchronous in ajax so if ajax is used asynchronously it never stops any other process on the page and works in parallel with other page functionalities. So will making ajax asynchronous work and not affect page speed. Whats your opinion on this.

asynchronous just means that the code doesn't wait for a response, it still sends the request to your server. So, if what you want is to make it so whenever someone clicks a link on your site it loads that page without refreshing the URL, no matter how it's coded, it's still going to make a request to your server. If you want the entire page to be replaced when clicking a link on your site and all the URL's are still accessible normally, the code could be very simple. Things will get more complex if your site has javascript functions that need to re-run whenever a new page is requested.

You are absolutely right the asynchronous means that it doesn't wait for the servers response but request is still sent. Is there pre-load technology where all the pages are pre-loaded a cache kind of a thing like on loading the home page all the pages are pre-loaded and asynchronous block might fit in in the preload section. Like all pages are fully loaded in background before any visible pageload. I wondered if this triavial feature could ever come like not going to other pages but loading them without a stress. Do you think we can a plugin for this and on very small sites it is used.
